# Where is catalina output location when running Tomcat from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, catalina.out

I would think it is the console output. But I don't see errors showing up in console when they are supposed to - terminal version of tomcat shows errors in catalina.out for the same actions that I am reproducing for Eclipse run Tomcat.

Comment: It's typically a path like `\path\to\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs\`

Comment: @Selaron I thought so too but I only see access logs in that directory - no Catalina logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the application had logback.xml configured trying to emit logs in some location but the path specified was a relative path instead of a full path and Eclipse's Tomcat was not able to use that relative path (not sure exactly why), but replacing relative path in logback.xml with a full path started emitting logs at ".metadata/..." in the workspace directory.